# Change phone number and email in paragraph to clickable link with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a paragraph with some address data, and now I want to replace with regex email and phone number to clickable link.

```
<div class="container">
  <p id="contactInfo">
    Address 27, Tokio 679 01<br>
    Tel: 0909000000<br>
    E-mail: exampplet@example.com
  </p>
</div>

<script>
var contact_info = document.getElementById('contactInfo');
    var html = contact_info.innerHTML;
    if (html) {
        var regex = /([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})/ig;
        contact_info.innerHTML = html.replace(regex, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
    }
</script>
```

now the email will change to a clickable link, but how can I change phone number to clickable link too?

I tried this: but it never working:

```
<script>
    var contact_info = document.getElementById('contactInfo');
    var html = contact_info.innerHTML;
    if (html) {
        var pattern = /^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[\W\D\s]*(\d[\W\D\s]*?\d[\D\W\s]*?\d)[\W\D\s]*(\d[\W\D\s]*?\d[\D\W\s]*?\d)[\W\D\s]*(\d[\W\D\s]*?\d[\D\W\s]*?\d[\W\D\s]*?\d)(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$/g;
        contact_info.innerHTML = html.replace(pattern, '<a href="tel:$1$2$3$4$5">$1$2$3$4$5</a>');
    }
</script>
```

Here is codepen example: [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/mask1/pen/ExmLYRM)

Comment: Be aware that HTML is not a regular language and cannot be safely handled with a regex. Either process the TextNodes in the DOM, or (probably more ideal) process them before they even enter the DOM, i.e. before they become part of HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different regex for mobile and email and then replace it accordingly.

```js
const contact_info = document.getElementById('contactInfo');
const html = contact_info.innerHTML;
if (html) {
  const emailRegex = /([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4})/ig;
  const mobileregex = /Tel:\s+((\+\d{1,2}\s?)?1?\-?\.?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4})/g;
  contact_info.innerHTML = html.replace(emailRegex, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>').replace(mobileregex, 'Tel: <a href="tel:$1">$1</a>');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="contactInfo">
    Address 27, Tokio 679 01<br> Tel: 0909000000<br> E-mail: exampplet@example.com
  </p>
</div>
```